# Rankine–Hugoniot relation and Shock curve

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the Burgers' equation
$$u_t+\left( \frac{u^2}{2} \right)_x=0$$
and flux function $f(u)=\frac{u^2}{2}$
and with initial conditions
$$u(x,0)=\begin{cases} 
x & x\leq 1 \\
      0 & 1< x 
   \end{cases}$$
The Rankine–Hugoniot relation for calculating the shock speed is:$$s(t)=\frac{f(u_R)-f(u_L)}{u_R-u_L}$$
If we want to use this relationship to calculate the shock speed at time $t=0$, are $u_R$ and $u_L$ any 2 values on either side of the discontinuity, or values at the exact location of the discontinuity. In the later case, we would have:
$$s(t)=\frac{f(0)-f(1)}{0-1}=-0.5$$

In addition to this, how exactly can we plot the shock curve? I know using the definition of characteristic curves, we get $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df(u)}{du}=u$$
Using this, I can plot the characteristic curves in the $xt$ plane and see where the curves meet. I am just confused which points of intersection are used for the shock curve.

Answer (score 2):

The essential trick in the method of characteristics is that the solution stays constant along them:
$$ \frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} = f'\Big( u\big(x(t), t\big) \Big) = f'\Big(u_0\big(x(t), t\big) \Big) = f'\Big(u_0\big(x_0(x(t), t)\big)  \Big)$$
In your case:
$$ \frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} = u = u_0 = \begin{cases} x_0 & x_0 \leq 1 \\ 0 & x_0 > 1 \end{cases}$$
You can solve this to obtain
$$x(t) = \begin{cases} x_0 + x_0 \cdot t  & x_0 \leq 1 \\ x_0 & x_0 > 1 \end{cases}. \tag{1} $$
Let's plot this:

[image]

As we can see, the shock forms around $x = 1$.
Let's do a zoom (with the blue characteristic for $x_0 = 1 - 10^{-3}$ and the orange one for $x_0 = 1 + 10^{-3}$:

[image]

We see that the characteristics clash already at $x = 1$ into each other (the shock is formed here).

The shock curve $\gamma(t)$ is indeed computed by RH:
$$s(t) = \gamma'(t) = \frac{f(u_L) - f(u_R)}{u_L -u_R} = \frac{u_L^2 - u_R^2}{2(u_L -u_R)} = 0.5 (u_L - u_R)\tag{2} $$

Now we can benefit from our analysis of the characteristics: We know that the solution $u$ on the right of the shock is just the initial value (again, $u$ stays constant along the chars), thus $u_R = 0$. The left state is a bit more complicated. We again know that it will be somehow related to the initial condition, but have to find out how. Precisely, we need the initial value $x_0\big(x(t), t\big)$ belonging to some point $ \big(x(t), t \big)$ of which we know it lies on a blue characteristic ( $x_0 \leq 1$). Taking a look at the equations for the characteristics $(1)$, we immediately have
$$x_0\big(x(t), t\big) = \frac{x}{1 + t} \tag{3}.$$
Back to the RH condition $(2)$: This now reads $$\gamma'(t) = \frac{1}{2} u_L$$
and because $u_L = u_0 = x_0 $ for blue characteristics, the ODE for $\gamma(t) $ reads
$$\gamma'(t) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\gamma}{1 + t} .$$
Here I substituted $\gamma(t)$ for $x(t)$ in equation $(3)$.
This seperable ODE [has the general solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%20%3D%200.5%20x%20%2F%20%281%20%2Bt%29)
$$ \gamma(t) = c \sqrt{1 + t}.$$

We know that the shock forms at time $t_0 = 0$ at position $x=1$, which defines $c$:
$$ 1 \overset{!}{=} c \sqrt{1 + 0} \Rightarrow c = 1.$$

To conclude, we can now plot the shock curve:

[image]

The non-linearity becomes more visible for later times $t > 1$.

Comment: No, you get $x'(t)=f'(z(t))$, $z(t)=u(x(t),t)$, and with $z'(t)=0$ one has $z(t)=z(0)=u(x(0),0)=u_0(x_0)$. So in short, the right side of $x'$ is constant, thus $x$ linear. The value for $x_0$ is implicit, for the point $x,t$ one would have to solve $x-x_0=t·f'(u_0(x_0))$. That there can be multiple solutions is the reason for shock fronts.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! I confused myself with conservation laws where the characteristics are indeed straight lines and transport equations with velocities $a(x)$, where you can get all sorts of things.

Answer (score 1):

If the shock front at time $t$ has position $s(t)$, $s(0)=1$, then it is the meeting point of the vertical characteristic $u_R=0$ from $x_0=s(t)$ and $x_0+tx_0=s(t)$ with $u_L=x_0<1$ from the left. The mean value determining the speed is thus
$$
s'(t)=\frac{\frac{s(t)}{1+t}+0}{2}\implies s(t)=\sqrt{1+t}.
$$